# json.load does not properly decode .json-file

Tags: python, json

I have a file called test.json with the following content.

```
{
"Nederbördsmängd": "7",
"Rådande väder": "13"
}
```

I want to load it into my python script as a json-object.

```py
with open("test.json",encoding='UTF-8') as json_data_file:
        schema = json.load(json_data_file)
print(json.dumps(schema,indent=2))
```

The output:

```
{
  "Nederb\u00f6rdsm\u00e4ngd": "7",
  "R\u00e5dande v\u00e4der": "13"
}
```

When I print the file directly without converting it to a json-object it works as expected.

```py
with open("test.json",encoding='UTF-8') as json_data_file:
        print(json_data_file.read())
```

The output:

```
{
"Nederbördsmängd": "7",
"Rådande väder": "13"
}
```

How do I load my file into my script as a json object without altering its content?
I'm using python 3.9.7.

Comment: To clarify: your issue is _not_ in `json.loads()`, which loads the file correctly (try `print(schema)`, which gives the exact output you expect). The issue is that when you _dump_ the object back to json, the default behavior of `json.dumps()` is to have `ensure_ascii=True`, which forces those unicode characters to be encoded as ASCII. Setting `ensure_ascii=False` in `json.dumps()` fixes this issue.

Comment: When I used to work with python it was encoding="utf-8".  I'm not sure if the capital letters might be an issue